# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having this error when I try to load my list of toys:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function react js

When I refresh the page, it shows the list for  just a moment and then the error appears. I have been googling for hours now and I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong. My goal is to be able to press a sort button and be able to sort the toys alphabetically, and then press it again to show the unordered toys.

If you have any advice, please send it my way. Thank you!

```
const ToyList = (props) => {
  const [toys, setToys] = useState([]);
  const [sortToys, setSortToys] = useState(false);
  const [startingToys, setStartingToys] = useState([]);

  // On launch we can save the inital order to state
  useEffect(() => {
    // Set the toys
    setToys(fetchToys());
    // Save this ordering
    setStartingToys(toys);
  }, []);


  // Whenever sortToys changes, we can also change toys
  // thus re-rendering the list in the order you want
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortToys) {
      setToys(toys.sort((a, b) => a.name.localCompare(b.name)));
    } else {
      setToys(startingToys);
    }
  }, [sortToys]);


  // Function to change the sort
  const handleSortChange = () => setSortToys(() => !sortToys);


    return (
       <div>
      <div className="sortDiv">
        <Button className="m-3" value="toy" onClick={handleSortChange}>Toys A-Z</Button>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      {props.toys.map(toy =>
        <Container fluid>
        <Row>
            <Col key={toy.id}>
                <Card style={{ width: '17rem' }} className='text-center'>
              <Link to={`/toys/${toy.id}`}>{toy.name}
              <Card.Img variant='top' src={toy.image_url} alt="toyimage" width="300" height="300" /></Link>
              </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        </Container> ) }   
        </div> 
    )
      }
      export default ToyList
```

My fetchToys action:

```
export function fetchToys() {
    return (dispatch) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/toys')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(toys=> dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_TOYS', 
        payload: toys
    }))
    }
}
```

Comment: So the issue is in my fetchToys action? I don't see where the problem is in that....  I didn't have an issue with any of this until recently.

Answer (score 0):

`export function fetchToys()` is wrong.
try this : `export function fetchToys(dispatch)`

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.